# Intended use for interfaces that extend classes

Tags: typescript

It appears that TypeScript 0.9+ provides the ability for interfaces to extend classes as follows:

```
class Foo implements IFoo {
    /**
     * This is bar
     */
    bar = 2;
}

interface IFoo extends Foo { }

var x: IFoo,
    y: Foo = new Foo();
```

Does anyone know the intention for this feature?

From my experience, the biggest value I get from it is that in IDEs (such as VS), it allows me to see the JSDoc when I type `x.bar` or `y.bar`. This is incredibly useful as it avoids having to have duplicate documentation for what is essentially the same property/method.

Because of the huge benefit in terms of documentation, I am leaning towards migrating a bunch of interfaces to use this style, but I don't want to do anything that may be taken out of the compiler at some point, or might cause other issues. Is there anything I should be aware of with regards to this feature? Is there another useful result of this feature that I should know about?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the actual intention, but it does provide a simple way to implement multiple inheritance without needing to create 3 spurious interfaces just for that purpose:

```
class Tractor {
....
}

class Trailer {
    ....
}


interface ITractorTrailer extends Tractor, Trailer {} 

class TractorTrailer implements ITractorTrailer {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know the intention for this feature?

Simply because it allows you to capture the type information of a class in an interface.

> but I don't want to do anything that may be taken out of the compiler at some point, or might cause other issues

Its a part of the *stabalized* language specification. See section `7.1` http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf

```
InterfaceDeclaration:
   interface Identifier TypeParametersopt InterfaceExtendsClauseopt ObjectType
InterfaceExtendsClause:
   extends ClassOrInterfaceTypeList
```

Explicitly `ClassOrInterfaceTypeList`